# Howto set Bing Maps custom pushpin anchor to bottom right

Tags: bing-maps

I have following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;         

     function GetMap()
     {
        // Initialize the map
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"),
                     {credentials:"<MYAPIKEY>", zoom: 16, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(63.564751, 8.586110), showMapTypeSelector: false, disableZooming: true }); 

        // Retrieve the location of the map center 
        var center = map.getCenter();

        // Define the pushpin location
        var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(63.563110, 8.582800);

        // Add a pin to the map
        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc, {icon:"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/cv_pushpin.png", height:168, width:107, anchor:new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,0), draggable: false});

        map.entities.push(pin);
     }
```

The issue I am having is here that the custom pushpin icon moves away while I am zooming in or out of the map. And I think the reason is here:

```
 anchor:new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,0)
```

According to the Bing docs, this sets the anchor of the custom pushpin to the upper left corner of thr image. However my anchor is in the bottom right corner. But I can't set correctly. Any hints?

I already tried anchor:new Microsoft.Maps.Point(1,1) or anchor:new Microsoft.Maps.Point(168,107) or anchor:new Microsoft.Maps.Point(107,168) - nothing seems to work like desired.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Hey guys, thanks for your answers! I ended up manually measuring the image, and found out even though the image had a fixed width, there is also some shadow and space on the right side of the image (even right of the pin) so the anchor point needs to be set (x,y) from the upper left (0,0) of the image exactly to the desired x/y coordinates on the image. Now it works finally. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main reason is because the center of your map is different than the location of the pushpin.

```
center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(63.564751, 8.586110)
```

vs

```
// Define the pushpin location
var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(63.563110, 8.582800);
```

If you want the map to zoom in and out with your pushpin in the center then these need to be the same.

As for the anchor, since (0,0) is the top left corner, to get the center you just need to use half the width and height of your pushpin. So (53, 84).

I created a working example in Jsfiddle so you can see the behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/bryantlikes/82BZA/1/

Comment: Many thanks for that great fiddle Bryant! That was a big help for me!

Answer (score 1):

The anchor is the correct property to use. Try using negative values to see if that helps. Try anchor:new Microsoft.Maps.Point(107,168) with an image of that size I'm finding that the bottom right corner of the image is tied to the pushpins location as expected.

Comment: Thanks rbrundritt! (also a great approach but I eventually figured it out)